# Spring Kafka Partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

What is the difference in the behavior of the below two code snippets to publish a message?

**Approach 1**

```
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("testmsg")
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "key").setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "test").build();

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

**Approach 2**

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("test", "testmsg");
```

**Topic Config:**

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
Topic:test   PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: test  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: test  Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: test  Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

**Observation:**

If there are 3 consumers, one per partition; Approach 1 leads to all messages consumed by a single consumer from a single partition. With Approach 2; consumption is equally split between the 3 partitions/consumers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

But you have an answer in your code.
The first one alongside with the `topic` provides `messageKey`.

The `messageKey` is really used to determine target partition if isn't specified explicitly:

```
/**
 * computes partition for given record.
 * if the record has partition returns the value otherwise
 * calls configured partitioner class to compute the partition.
 */
private int partition(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, byte[] serializedKey, byte[] serializedValue, Cluster cluster) {
    Integer partition = record.partition();
    return partition != null ?
            partition :
            partitioner.partition(
                    record.topic(), record.key(), serializedKey, record.value(), serializedValue, cluster);
}
```

where `DefaultPartitioner` does this:

```
List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
int numPartitions = partitions.size();
if (keyBytes == null) {
    int nextValue = nextValue(topic);
        ...
} else {
   // hash the keyBytes to choose a partition
   return Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % numPartitions;
}
```

So, all messages with the same `key` are sent to the same partition. Otherwise they are placed to the topic round-robin manner.